# Hammerspoon Keystroke not working on new MAC

Tags: keystroke, hammerspoon

I used to have hammerspoon configured on my previous MAC but when I switched to the new MAC (M1) the keystroke is not working while other functions are.
Any idea if the new MAC could be blocking Hammerspoon to paste the message?

the script that I am using is similar to

hs.hotkey.bind({"option","cmd"}, "h", function() hs.eventtap.keyStrokes("TEST") end)

The expectation is that the text TEST would be added to where the cursor is at, e.g. Slack